# How to Set Cache-Control Headers for varnish/cachewall

Tags: apache, varnish, cache-control, varnish-vcl, response-headers

I little bit confused with my server. Its not returning cache-control headers with varnish and if I try to add cache control headers manually via `.htaccess` then varnish is not returning appropriate headers for HIT or MISS and Age numbers.

I also do not know how to edit /etc/varnish/default.vcl ?

I am using a VPS and details:

- cPanel Version 72.0 (build 10)
- Apache Version 2.4.34
- PHP Version 5.6.37
- Architecture x86_64

What can I do? I have tried other similar solutions and they did not work maybe outdated or i do not understand what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because of imperfect/imcomplete articles posted on the web.

I found complete installation detail on the github and fixed the issue

https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-cpanel

Its very difficult for a newbie guy to know the your installation article is incomplete and leave you in the middle to installation.